# Listview customization on item tapped - quick preview -Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, instagram

Is there any way to achieve the following behavior on a listview

On item tapped it opens up a preview of the image or video, like Instagram . I seen this behavior all over iPhones, is when you tapped on an item and then a quick preview pops up with options. 
Is there any plugin for this and actually what is the name of this behavior?

[image]

Comment: The name of this is actionsheets on xamarin forms, this is the link of the documentation   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the XF ActionSheets note that it's a DialogFragment on Android i.e. it shows the native Android control in this case

```
 string action = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(Title, cancelText, destructButtonText, listOfOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
                switch (action)
                {
                    case A:
                        DoSomething();
                        break;

                    case B:
                        DoSomethingElse();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

Goodluck,

Feel free to get back if you have queries

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

but you have to amke your own "options" unlike `XF ActionSheets` that has built in "yes or no" options

for opening popup

```
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new YourPopupPage());
```

for closing popup

```
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
```

Goodluck

Comment: so , what are you referring to is that I need to add the popup inside the listviewcell ? and and then add a regular actionsheet ?